# How to access a Hyper link using XPath

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

What is correct format for using XPath?

Does XPath vary with the browser?

```
drchrome.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Google')]")).click();
```

Comment: It should't change with browser, at least not this one. Ttry to use an attribute like `href` instead of text, if you still have issues then please add more info, url of the page and used selector and browser name.

Comment: Add your HTML code, so that we could help you how to locate then hyperlink.

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you are trying to locate Hyperlink Element & you have `'/a'` attribute, just forget about the XPath method and try using **linkText** element Locator.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Page</title>
     <body>
          <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
     <body>
</html>
```

In this situation use:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Google")).click();
```

Answer (score 5):

As far as i know xpath doesn't depends on any browser. Make sure you have created correct xpath it will work.

Second : It's depend on your tag which attribute it has and how efficient you are in xpath.

For example this is the simple hyperlink:

```
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot" name="hotnetwork" class="js-gps-track">Hot Network Questions</a>
```

So here i can create the xpath to locate the same in different ways like :

```
//a[@name='hotnetwork']
```

OR

```
//a[@class='js-gps-track']
```

OR combine both attribute for uniqueness like :

```
//a[@name='hotnetwork'][@class='js-gps-track']
```

OR if you want to access the link using its text then you can use `contains()` method

```
//a[contains(text(),'Hot Network')]
```

Note : It will locate the element based on match found with your given string (Hot Network)

If you require to locate an element if self or its child tag contains some text then using dot `.` in contains method as you are using :

```
 //a[contains(.,'Hot Network')]
```

OR you can use `text()` method like :

```
//a[text()=' Hot Network Questions']
```

While using `text()` method you have to pass the full link text including spaces else it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to locate Hyperlink Element try **linkText** element Locator or **Partial LinkText**.

Example using linktext:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("click here")).click();
```

Example using partial linktext:

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("here")).click();
```